# Poor SSAS Tabular / DAX Performance

Tags: sql-server, ssas, dax, query-performance, ssas-tabular

I am new to SSAS Tabular and DAX.
I have built a data model and processed successfully. Now, I am in the middle of recoding SSRS report to use SSAS Tabular instead of hitting tables and indexed views in data warehouse.

The fact table that this particular DAX query I am writing against has a size of ~220 million records.
Below is the query:

```
DEFINE
VAR Ind_Fact_Summ_Matter_By_Day_By_Posted =     
//SAMPLE(1000,
    ADDCOLUMNS
    (
        SUMMARIZE
        (
            'Revenue Summary',
            'Revenue Summary'[AK_Tran_Date],
            'Revenue Summary'[AK_Post_Date],
            'Revenue Summary'[AK_Period],
            'Revenue Summary'[AK_Current_Matter],
            'Revenue Summary'[AK_Matter],
            'Revenue Summary'[AK_Exchange_DateRange]
        ),
        "Debt_Total_Outstanding", CALCULATE([Total Debt Total Outstanding]), --CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Debt_Total_Outstanding]))
        "Fees_WIP_Amount", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Fees_WIP_Amount])),
        "Disbs_Soft_WIP", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Disbs_Soft_WIP])),
        "Disbs_Hard_WIP", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Disbs_Hard_WIP])),
        "Disbs_Total_WIP", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Disbs_Total_WIP])),
        "Fees_Base_Amount", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Fees_Base_Amount])),
        "Debt_Total_Billed", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Debt_Total_Billed])),
        "Net_Revenue", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Net_Revenue])),
        "Fees_Net_Revenue", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Fees_Net_Revenue])),
        "Other_Revenue", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Other_Revenue])),
        "Total_Cost_Amt", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Total_Cost_Amt])),
        "Fees_WIP_reserve", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Fees_WIP_Reserve])),
        "Other_Disbs_WIP_Reserve", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Other_Disbs_WIP_Reserve])),
        "Debt_Total_Reserve", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Debt_Total_Reserve])),
        "Billable_Hours", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Billable_Hours])),
        "Partner_Billable_Hours", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Partner_Billable_Hours])),
        "Legal_Staff_Billable_Hours", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Legal_Staff_Billable_Hours])),
        "Standard_Revenue_No_Secondment", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Standard_Revenue_No_Secondment])),
        "Standard_Revenue_Secondment", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Standard_Revenue_Secondment])),
        "Fees_Standard_Revenue", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Fees_Standard_Revenue])),
        "Fees_Billed_WIP_Writeoff", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Fees_Billed_WIP_Writeoff])),
        "Debt_Writeoff_Secondment", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Debt_Writeoff_Secondment])),
        "Debt_Writeoff_No_Secondment", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Debt_Writeoff_No_Secondment])),
        "WIP_Reserve", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Fees_WIP_Reserve]) + SUM('Revenue Summary'[Other_Disbs_WIP_Reserve])),
        "Total_Reserve", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Fees_WIP_Reserve]) + SUM('Revenue Summary'[Other_Disbs_WIP_Reserve]) + SUM('Revenue Summary'[Debt_Total_Reserve]))
    )
//  ,RAND()
//)
EVALUATE 
    Ind_Fact_Summ_Matter_By_Day_By_Posted
```

As you can see, it is pretty straightforward DAX query - aggregating some metrics.
'Revenue Summary' is the big fact table I was talking about, which has 220 million records.
When I ran the query in DAX Studio, it failed due to memory constraint.
When I did SAMPLE or TOPN 1000, it took 5 minutes! and that was only returning 1 aggregated metrics (I commented the rest - just for testing purpose)!

I am not sure if it's the model, the DAX, the hardware or the combo of them, which cause such a poor performance.
The dev server where the tabular model is hosted is virtual server with the following specs (based on CPU-Z):

- Intel Xeon E5 (8 cores, 4 sockets)
- 90 GB RAM
- Memory type: EDO (not sure what this is?!)
- DRAM Frequeny: 66.0 Mhz (slow as??)
- At rest, 47% of RAM is used. When I ran the query (without the TOPN 1000), it went up until it failed due to memory constraint and CPU utilization was quite high ~80-90%.

Also, as I mentioned above, I am recoding SSRS report which has been written using indexed views.
Note than the query is only part of the bigger query which a report uses.
The report runs about a minute hence I am exploring a way to speed it up using SSAS Tabular.
When I did TOP 1000 of the equivalent query in SQL using the indexed view, it only took 1 sec, so looks like SSAS Tabular fails me here?!

What should I do to improve the performance significantly?
Anything I did wrong?

Any guidance will be much appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT: Using SSAS 2016 in Tabular/In-Memory/Import mode (not DirectQuery)

Comment: Just wondering, DirectQuery mode is not enabled, right?

Comment: @AlexanderVolok I just checked in SSMS, the database is in Import mode not DirectQuery mode.

Comment: The first thing I would do is comment out all measures but one, run the query and time it. Then comment out all but the next measure and time it. I am assuming one or more measures are expensive or can be optimized. Once you have found the culprit post the DAX for that measure and any other measures it refers to.

Comment: @GregGalloway thanks for  the tip. FYI, all of them are not measures but fields straight from the data source (SQL Server table), except the first one, [Total Debt Total Outstanding].

I am thinking the slowness could be caused by the fact that the fact table is quite big with lots of metrics fields, and each metrics fields' cardinality is high due to lots of distinct values, which does not help the compression hence performance of the tabular model. Not sure what to do to optimize.

If I import just that fact table without any other tables, the model database uses ~38GB of RAM by itself.

Comment: How many rows would the query return if it finished? Is the query fast without Total Debt Total Outstanding?

Comment: Can you share your model script (.json file with TMSL)?

Comment: Why did you put CALCULATE() around every SUM() and added the measures with ADDCOLUMNS outside the SUMMARIZE? You could use the standard syntax of SUMMARIZE; listing all group by colums, and the needed measures in one function? See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492171.aspx

Comment: @GregGalloway it should return ~94 Million rows based on the equivalent SQL query run against the data source. Big numbers I know, but even when I only do TOPN(1000,...) and only one metrics, the query fails to complete in DAX Studio with the following error: "The operation has been cancelled because there is not enough memory available for the application. If using 32-bit version of the product, consider upgrading to the 64-bit version or increasing the amount of memory available on the machine.". I am using 64-bit and at rest with model loaded it has ~40 GB free RAM, but used up during query

Comment: @KrystianSakowski, here is the JSON file of the model.. https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByVFAAeL8SDfRWpqQUdWbnU2Uk9rVURYLXNQdXVQNzVOaW1R/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @TJ_ yes, I initally used SUMMARIZE (and SUMMIZECOLUMNS) but I read that SUMMARIZE has performance issue as per this article https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/best-practices-using-summarize-and-addcolumns/

Comment: What are you doing with a 94 million row dataset in SSRS? Is the query parameterized to filter down? I feel like optimizing this query is pointless since even if it were fast SSRS can't handle 94 million rows. And I'm assuming TOPN(1000) is just for testing and not what you will actually do in SSRS, is that correct?

Comment: @GregGalloway, as I am recoding the SSRS report, the stored proc used uses this indexed view which generates 94 millions rows. It is used to get some metrics and will be filtered further down the code. I know 94 millions are pretty big number but I thought tabular will be handle that since it's enterprise ready solution (or not?)

Comment: @iKnowNothing so include the real filters in your DAX query in your question and let us know how it performs. It is a waste of time to get a query that returns 94 million rows to return in a reasonable amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you use Summarize to sum some of the columns - but not all!
you can use Summarizecolumns and simply summarize all of the columns in one go, so instead of:

```
VAR Ind_Fact_Summ_Matter_By_Day_By_Posted =     
//SAMPLE(1000,
    ADDCOLUMNS
    (
        SUMMARIZE
        (
            'Revenue Summary',
            'Revenue Summary'[AK_Tran_Date],
            'Revenue Summary'[AK_Post_Date],
            'Revenue Summary'[AK_Period],
            'Revenue Summary'[AK_Current_Matter],
            'Revenue Summary'[AK_Matter],
            'Revenue Summary'[AK_Exchange_DateRange]
        ),
        "Debt_Total_Outstanding", CALCULATE([Total Debt Total Outstanding]), --CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Debt_Total_Outstanding]))
        "Fees_WIP_Amount", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Fees_WIP_Amount])),
        "Disbs_Soft_WIP", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Disbs_Soft_WIP])),
        "Disbs_Hard_WIP", CALCULATE(SUM('Revenue Summary'[Disbs_Hard_WIP])),
```

Or whatever else you've got in there, just go for:

```
VAR Ind_Fact_Summ_Matter_By_Day_By_Posted =     
SUMMARIZE
            (
                'Revenue Summary',
                'Revenue Summary'[AK_Tran_Date],
                'Revenue Summary'[AK_Post_Date],
                'Revenue Summary'[AK_Period],
                'Revenue Summary'[AK_Current_Matter],
                'Revenue Summary'[AK_Matter],
                'Revenue Summary'[AK_Exchange_DateRange], 
'Revenue Summary'[Debt_Total_Outstanding],
'Revenue Summary'[Fees_WIP_Amount],
'Revenue Summary'[Disbs_Soft_WIP],
'Revenue Summary'[Disbs_Hard_WIP]
            )
```

There's absolutely no reason in the "add columns" section to add a calculated measure (unless it's already predefined). In the ADDCOLUMNS section we add the attributes that we want to group by them.